# Group by select that returns only groups with updated rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a Table "Postings"

```
CREATE TABLE POSTINGS(
    Account_FK INT,
    Department_FK INT,
    Project_FK INT,
    Company_FK INT,
    Year INT,
    Month INT,
    Amount float,
    Handled BIT
)
```

Im trying to make a select statement that will select the sum of Amounts for each company each month.
Like this:

```
SELECT Company_FK, Year, Month, Sum(Amount)
FROM Postings
GROUP BY Company_FK, Year, Month
```

But i will only need the rows that have not been handled. E.g. the rows with Handled = 0

```
SELECT Company_FK, Year, Month, Sum(Amount)
FROM Postings
WHERE Handled = 0
GROUP BY Company_FK, Year, Month
```

Now this query will sum up only the rows with Handled = 0 for the Company each year and month.
But i will also need the sums to include all the other rows for the company. I mean, if one row in the company is not handled. I will need to return the company sum of all company-rows.

So if Company_FK = 1 has three postings. All of which have handled = 1. Then this company could be ignored. But if Company_FK = 2 has three postings. And one of them has handled = 0, then i would need to return the sum of all three rows.

Do you understand what i mean?

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you looked at trying a Having Statement..? here is a good link to look at that will explain how to use GroupBy and OrderBy.. http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqlgroupby.php

Comment: btw I changed your original query to add the as "Amount" to make it a column name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT distinct c.Company_FK, c.Year, c.Month, b.Amount FROM Postings c
INNER JOIN
(SELECT Company_FK, Year, Month, Sum(Amount) as 'Amount'
FROM Postings
GROUP BY Company_FK, Year, Month) b ON c.Company_FK = b.Company_FK and c.Year = b.Year and c.Month = b.Month
WHERE c.Handled = 0
```

Comment: I will +1 this answer when you add the missing `FROM` in your query ;-)

Comment: This does not run, there is no FROM aside from the one in the subquery

Comment: @aF, almost there!  It wouldn't let me alias the Postings table

Comment: @aF. +1. I could've edit your answer, but I always give a heads up first, as to not hurt some sensitivities :-)

Comment: @Lamak I know what you mean, with me you can do it ^^

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `HAVING` statement after your `GROUP BY`

```
HAVING COUNT(*) > SUM(CONVERT(INT, Handled))
```

You will need to remove the `WHERE` clause as well, because the `HAVING` will be the filter

Full Query:

```
SELECT Company_FK, Year, Month, Sum(Amount)
FROM Postings
GROUP BY Company_FK, Year, Month
HAVING COUNT(*) > SUM(CONVERT(INT, Handled))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Company_FK, Year, Month, Sum(Amount) as "Amount"
FROM Postings
GROUP BY Company_FK, Year, Month
HAVING COUNT(*) > SUM(CONVERT(INT, Handled))
```

Comment: Need to remove the where clause

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Company_FK, Year, Month, Sum(Amount)
FROM Postings p
WHERE Exists (select top 1 1  from Postings po where p.company_fk=po.company_fk and Handled=0 )
GROUP BY Company_FK, Year, Month
```